# FFImage is not loading 5 Mb imges from url

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, ffimageloading

I tried to load the image on ffimageloading:CachedImage from URL, few images which are of 5 MBs are not loading in Android Tablet.

Please suggest to me what should I do about the issue?

```
                  <ListView    
                       BackgroundColor="#171921"
                        HasUnevenRows="True"
                        HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding DisplayData.ImagesSASUrl}"
                        SelectionMode="None"
                        VerticalOptions="Start">
                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate x:DataType="x:String">
                                <ViewCell>
                                    <Grid>
                                        <ffimageloading:CachedImage
                                            Margin="10"
                                            Aspect="AspectFit"
                                            BitmapOptimizations="True"
                                            DownsampleToViewSize="True"
                                            HeightRequest="200"
                                            LoadingPlaceholder="imageloading.png"
                                            Source="{Binding .}" />
                                    </Grid>
                                </ViewCell>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListView>
```

Comment: Have you already tried to do it in your CSharp code behind? `await ImageService.Instance.LoadStream(token => photo.OpenReadAsync()) .DownSample(500, 500)` or added some retries? 
What error message do you see in your application output? Do smaller images load fine?

Comment: images in Kbs are loading fine only for MBs image issue is coming, with adding tries I did but still no luck.  I got error image once when Image didn't load for longer time

Comment: Could you share what the error message is?

Comment: I just got error img on ErrorPlaceholder="" on xaml but no error msg as such

Comment: Try to provide a custom config in platform project , or use `CachedImage.Error` to figure out the error message , check https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading/issues/990 .